# Форма закрывается с ошибкой

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы при изменении значения в comboBox база данных выводилась в datagridview. Вроде бы все работает, но при закрытии формы выдает ошибку:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Сам код:

```
namespace Cu
{
    public partial class VoucherForm : Form
    {
        public VoucherForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void VoucherCountry()
        {
            dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
            dataGridView1.AllowUserToOrderColumns = false;
            dataGridView1.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
            dataGridView1.AllowDrop = false;
            dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;

            DB dB = new DB();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Voucher WHERE Name_Country= @nC", dB.ConnectionSQL());
            command.Parameters.Add("@nC", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = comboBox1.SelectedValue;
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

            dB.OpenSQL();
            adapter.SelectCommand = command;
            adapter.Fill(table);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
            dB.ClodeSQL();
        }


        private void VoucherForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.countryTableAdapter.Fill(this.cursacDat.Country);
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            VoucherCountry();
        }
```

Comment: Проверьте, что вот это `@nC` у вас одинаковое во всех местах, что вы случайно, например, не указали русскую `С`.

Comment: @AlexF Отладчик ругается на `adapter.Fill(table);`

Comment: @AlexF Если бы я знал ответ, то я бы не задавал этот вопрос...

Comment: @AlexF Не совсем понимаю, что вы имеете ввиду. Если вы о "Стеке вызовов" то выдает что-то вроде этого [ссылка](https://ibb.co/jfcYzXk)